# Transmit bitrate shown in `iw` is unexpectedly low

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

```
> iw dev wlp5s0 link

Connected to 00:35:1a:41:2d:cf (on wlp5s0)
    SSID: eduroam
    freq: 5240
    RX: 59188796 bytes (179767 packets)
    TX: 351043602 bytes (273799 packets)
    signal: -59 dBm
    tx bitrate: 6.0 MBit/s

    bss flags:  short-slot-time
    dtim period:    1
    beacon int: 102


> iw dev wlp5s0 station dump

Station 00:35:1a:41:2d:cf (on wlp5s0)
    inactive time:  176 ms
    rx bytes:   59188796
    rx packets: 179767
    tx bytes:   351043602
    tx packets: 273799
    tx retries: 0
    tx failed:  396
    signal:     -59 dBm
    signal avg: -59 dBm
    tx bitrate: 6.0 MBit/s
    rx bitrate: 78.0 MBit/s VHT-MCS 4 VHT-NSS 2
    authorized: yes
    authenticated:  yes
    preamble:   long
    WMM/WME:    yes
    MFP:        no
    TDLS peer:  no
```

I see that my transmit bitrate is unexpectedly low, and I can confirm that upload speeds are slower than they could be (if I connect using a USB tether to my phone I get up/down speeds of 80Mbit/sec on this network).

I've fiddled with `iw`, powersave is off, but I haven't succeeded at getting my transmit rate up. This is a year old high-end laptop, so it shouldn't have an issue (I don't recall such an issue when I ran windows). Any ideas on how to tackle this issue?

Running the latest Linux mint 18.1 on an MSI Ghost laptop.

### Update:

@dirkt provided some troubleshooting tips in the comments which lead me to a driver update that has half-fixed the problem. My receive bitrate is now 240Mbit, but my transmit bitrate is still stuck at 6Mbit.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184

```
> iw dev wlp5s0 station dump
Station 00:35:1a:2e:07:2f (on wlp5s0)
    inactive time:  396 ms
    rx bytes:   234425411
    rx packets: 180469
    tx bytes:   33988923
    tx packets: 95897
    tx retries: 0
    tx failed:  248
    signal:     -60 dBm
    signal avg: -58 dBm
    tx bitrate: 6.0 MBit/s
    rx bitrate: 240.0 MBit/s VHT-MCS 5 40MHz short GI VHT-NSS 2
    authorized: yes
    authenticated:  yes
    preamble:   long
    WMM/WME:    yes
    MFP:        no
    TDLS peer:  no

> lspci -nn
<removed irrelevant entries>
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)

> sudo ethtool -i wlp5s0
driver: ath10k_pci
version: 4.4.0-77-generic
firmware-version: SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:05:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Comment: In general, the driver will adjust the bitrate to the current circumstances on the channel. As it's a laptop, try it in different locations with different APs on different channels, and see if the bitrate doesn't change.

Comment: I've tried many locations, and yes, some are better, however my phone is many times faster than my laptop from any location, and I never had these issues in windows. I've been trying to get the windows drivers to work on linux, but haven't had any luck with that just yet, that it's a linux drivers issue is my best hope so far.

Comment: I've seen Linux Wifi driver developers complaining that some of the newer Wifi chips mostly rely on closed-source firmware to get everything working, and that it's really a pain to write a good driver for that. So "driver issue" isn't unlikely. Figure out what your chipset is (`lspci -nn` or `lsusb`, look at the 4 digit hex vendor/device ids), google for that in the form of `0123:4567` to see if this is a known issue, file a bug with the developers if it isn't.

Comment: @dirkt than you a ton for that information, I didn't know to search on that ID and found a number of sources. This one in particular pointed me to a driver that has "half fixed" the problem! https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184  My receive bitrate is 240Mbit now and works like my phone, but transmit is still pegged at 6Mbit and slow.

Answer (score 1):

(Wrote up comment as answer.)

I've seen Linux Wifi driver developers complaining that some of the newer Wifi chips mostly rely on closed-source firmware to get everything working, and that it's really a pain to write a good driver for that. So "driver issue" isn't unlikely.

Figure out what your chipset is (lspci -nn or lsusb, look at the 4 digit hex vendor/device ids), google for that in the form of 0123:4567 to see if this is a known issue, file a bug with the developers if it isn't.

According to your comment, the [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184) is already reported. Put yourself on the subscribe list for the bug (and maybe add a comment explaining your situation), so you'll be kept informed when it's fixed.

Comment: It's not clear though that, that particular bug report is exactly related to this. It seems that they're dealing with support issues in general (and it's 2 years old). Whereas I'm dealing with this transmit bitrate issue. I'm not quite clear even exactly where I should report this issue as a bug. Also, I'm on linux mint, so I'm not sure if I should direct issues to the mint community or ubuntu community.

Answer (score 0):

On some 802.11ac Qualcom chipsets (I experienced it with QCA988x), it is well known that the transmit rate computed by the card chip is not transferred to the "ath10k" Linux kernel driver. Hence the driver always advertizes 6 Mbps transmit rate.

Probably the same applies to your QCA6174 chipset.