# How to install (and validate) windows network drivers in linux (mint)

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, windows

I've had [issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363293/transmit-bitrate-shown-in-iw-is-unexpectedly-low/364478#364478) with linux drivers for my wifi network card, I'm now attempting to install the windows network drivers.

I've installed the windows drivers via the Windows Network Drivers gui.

[image]

Now I'm trying to verify if that driver is in use:

```
> sudo lspci -v
# cut irrelevant parts #
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Killer N1525 Wireless-AC
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at f6800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=8/8 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Kernel driver in use seems to be the original linux driver there right? I'm absolutely no expert here (aside from the last few weeks of tinkering).

**What do I need to do enable the new windows driver?**

From a youtube tutorial I tried the following (without the slightest idea why I was doing it):

```
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
sudo ndiswrapper -m
sudo ndiswrapper -mi
```

I've also done:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

If I attempt to blacklist the existing wifi drivers by adding `blacklist ath10k-pci` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` then run `modprobe -r ath10k-pci`, `modprobe ath10k-pci`, I see this in dmesg and it seems to load the current drivers anyway. I'm certainly doing something wrong, but not sure what.

```
[ 1519.468092] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:05:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[ 1520.701796] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: qca6174 hw2.1 (0x05010000, 0x003405ff sub 1a56:1525) fw SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
```

Comment: It seems that are people putting it to work with Linux native drivers https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213500

Comment: The card works with the native drivers, but my transmit bitrate is pegged at 6Mbit, RX bitrate is 200Mbit+ with a good signal. I've posted a variety of questions all over the internet about that issue. There's a link to an open question about it in the first sentence, "issues". I've added a bounty to that question now. I see that the last entry of this link is, "Everything working, but the card has a low performance. I'll mark as solved so I can work on the performance issue." That's about where I stand and why I'm trying the windows drivers.

Comment: For it to work you should blacklist the linux native kernel driver for starters.

Comment: I tried blacklisting the native driver by adding `blacklist ath10k_pci` to `/etc/modprob.d/blacklist`, reboot, but it doesn't show a Kernel driver at all when I do `lspci -v` anymore. unblacklist and reboot and now it shows the kernel driver is `ath10k_pci` but I've lost wifi networking. I'm hacking here, I don't know what all these actions do yet. I do data science, I'm pretty clueless about kernel modules.

Comment: For putting the Windows drivers to work (if possible) you wont want the Linux driver using the card (both cant be active at the same time). Unfortunately, that is all I can say, as I havent tried to do this for years now; let´s see if someone that has done it more recently is able to guide you in more detail.